# check for keypress during php routine

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a feeling this is impossible as PHP is server side, but I was wondering if there was some kind of hack here which would make it possible.

I have a fairly simple PHP function which gets a bunch of email addresses from various wordpress users and sends an email out:

```
foreach ( $results as $user ) {
    usleep(50000);
    wp_mail( $user->user_email, $pTitle, $temp, $headers ); 
}
```

There could be several hundred emails at a time. Every so often I want to cancel the sending out once it has started. Is there a way that this could be done? Has anyone had this problem before and found a solution?

Just wondering...

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, which means you cannot detect keypresses using PHP alone. What you can do though, is to create a child process that handles mail sending. The child process identifier can be sent back to the client. When keypress is detected by JS on the client, make an AJAX call (with the child process ID as data) that will call a script on your server which will terminate your child process. The exact implementation is up to you, and extremely broad: if you have a specific problem statement, you are welcome to update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: I would store a value in a database or a special file that indicates if the script may send mails or not. Check from within the loop if the database value is set to e.g. 0 or the specific file is created. Ifso, exit the loop `break` and do additional things, like storing what mail you sent last so you can continue from there later on.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas - I am working on it...